# What is the fail-safe standard operating procedure if private key of peer is compromised or lost in hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

There are several example and tutorials in setting up hyper ledger fabric network. We are setting up byfn across demo machines. We would like to build upon Standard Operating Procedure for deployment.

One of the scenarios is what is process if the private key of the peer / channel in a system participant is compromised in a theft or hardware crash?

Comment: Why the Downvotes? Can the person down voting explain?

Answer (score 2):

In case the private key of an identity is compromised, you need to issue a CRL update in all channels that the organization of that identity participates in.

Comment: Reference - http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html?highlight=Revocation

Comment: Reference - http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/fabric-ca-commands.html?highlight=Revocation

Comment: Are the above links good enough or more documentation is available.